# Настройки yandex карты с помощью css

Tags: html5, css3

Белые квадраты идут фоном, то есть нужно саму карту по диагонали сделать, не понимаю, что писать. Карта встает прямоугольником обычным. Знаю, что задается это всё как-то через before, но ведь у меня фон не просто белый, там картинка (квадраты). Help

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подошло решение?

Comment: Еще не пробовал, но думаю оно идеально подойдет, большое спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что в данном случае будет уместнее SVG использовать.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1000 100" preserveaspectratio="none" class="traingle-left">
  <polygon points="0,0   0,100   1000,00   1000,0"></polygon>
</svg>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 1000 100" preserveaspectratio="none" class="traingle-right">
  <polygon points="1000,0   1000,100   0,100   0,100"></polygon>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/Odinokun/pen/LWyrab?editors=1100

Comment: А можно ли, чтобы вместо свг треугольников был фон ?

Comment: Этот вариант решения подходит если у Вас просто заливка цветом, как на рисунке в вопросе.
Если же нужны треугольники с рисунком, то просто сделайте у блока с картой 2 псевдоэлемента, которым задайте фон вырезанными треугольниками в формате png.

Comment: Не поможете с кодом ? через ::before и ::after ? В первый с таким сталкиваюсь.

Comment: Например вот так http://codepen.io/Odinokun/pen/RpZOqd?editors=1100

Comment: Большое спасибо :)